# Redis server is not having connection in production

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis, render.com

I am was building a chat webapp and it is done. This is the tools I am using -- >

Client : React, socket.io-client, chakra-ui etc.

Server: Node, express, socket.io

Database: Postgresql, Redis

Now I am using express session to store user information in the cookies and into redis so user doesn't have to login every time. This is how I did it -->

```
const session = require("express-session");
const redisClient = require("../redis");
const RedisStore = require("@goberman/connect-redis")(session);
require("dotenv").config();

const sessionMiddleWare = session({
  secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
  credentials: true,
  name: "$id",
  store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "true" : "auto",
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
    sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "none" : "lax",
  },
});
```

Now, I deployed the front-end on netlify and backend-database on render.com. I connected the psql using pg and redis using ioredis and I have set the configurations correctly. The psql database is working correctly because when I create an account the user infos are being stored in the psql database and for a split moment I am being directed to the home page of my app and getting kicked out. I checked the application from the browser to see the cookies and there is no cookies being set up. This is strange behaviour and I connected the ioredis with the render.com's redis instance like this

```
const Redis = require("ioredis");
require("dotenv").config()

const redisClient = new Redis(process.env.REDIS_URL);
```

The REDIS_URL is the provided Internal url by render.com. And my server and my databases are in the same region and account. I connected the redis instance in my command prompt and try to get the keys I get this error message

```
singapore-redis.render.com:6379> keys *
Error: Server closed the connection
singapore-redis.render.com:6379>
```

I tried to look up to the documentation of both render.com and ioredis in case I am doing something wrong with connecting the redis instance with my server but there is nothing wrong.